# Struggling to understand lme4 model syntax and nesting

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I am working on implementing a model in R. I thought I had a pretty good approach, but one of my collaborators has pointed out that the model degrees of freedom from lmerTest don't make sense for the interaction term.

First, a description of the experimentIn my data I have two fixed effects: "Species" is categorical, with 4 levels. "Induction" is categorical, with 3 levels. I also have a random effect "Genotype". In the experiment, each Species had three possible genotypes, thus a given individual has a Species, Induction, and Genotype. However, the Genotypes are unique to each species. For example, Genotype A,B,C belong only to Species 1, while Genotypes D, E, F belong only to Species 2, etc. I also have a continous covariate "biomass".

Some example data:

```
test_dat <- data.frame(
    "response" = c(rnorm(288)), 
    "Induction" = c(rep(c(rep(c(rep("1", 2), rep("2",2), rep("3",2)),12)),4)), 
    "Species" = c(rep(c(rep("A",18), rep("B", 18), rep("C",18), rep("D",18)),4)), 
    "GenotypeID" = c(rep(c(rep(c(rep("1", 6), rep("2",6), rep("3", 6)),4)),4)),
    "biomass" = rnorm(288))
```

To make the unique nature of each genotype explicit, you can run:

```
test_dat$UniqueGeno <- paste(test_dat$Species,test_dat$GenotypeID, sep="")
```

The model I thought I could run is

```
ex_mod <- lmer(response ~ Induction * Species + biomass +(1|Genotype), test_dat)
```

However this results in the following output from `anova(ex_mod, type = 2)`

```
Type II Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                  Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF   DenDF F value Pr(>F)
Induction         4.2500 2.12498     2 267.078  2.1428 0.1193
Species           3.6591 1.21971     3   8.056  1.2300 0.3602
biomass           0.0025 0.00252     1 274.821  0.0025 0.9599
Induction:Species 8.3486 1.39144     6 267.143  1.4031 0.2135
```

My understanding is that the DenDF for `Induction` and `Induction:Species` should be much lower, as it should be working with the mean of genotypes. Since each genotype is unique to a species, I am wondering if there is a more complex way of nesting the error term to get a more accurate model.

Thanks for your help